# Is it possible to perfectly forward a "non-generic" type without using SFINAE or writing multiple versions?

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae, perfect-forwarding

I understand how perfect forwarding works in the usual case:

```
template <typename T> 
void f(T &&arg) { 
  E(std::forward<T>(arg)));
}
```

Is it possible to perfectly forward a "non-generic" type such as some form of `std::string` without using SFINAE or writing multiple versions?

```
/* Likely some kind of template. */
/* template <typename T> */
void f(/* Something goes here*/ arg) {
  E(std::forward</* Something goes here. */>(arg);
}
```

The following should be true:

```
f(std_str_obj); // Lvalue forwarded as const lvalue ref.
f("hello"); // Temporary forwarded as rvalue reference.
f(1); // Error, not a std::string or convertible to std::string.
```

I'm suspecting that the only way is to still write a function template and use some form of SFINAE to restrict it (in which case I can figure something out on my own), but I was wondering if there was some simple way that I'm missing.

Comment: `void f(std::string&& arg) {E(std::forward<std::string>(arg));}` should do it.

Comment: @RSahu: That won't accept an lvalue.

Comment: `void f(std::string arg)` should do.

Comment: @BЈовић: That would create a copy for lvalues, I think.

Comment: @user3521733 Unless you modify it, std::string is just doing shallow copy. But you are right - such function will not work correctly for `std::string&`

Comment: It looks like you want to say "let `T` be some kind of reference to `std::string`, deduce which kind from the actual argument". It is not exactly clear why you want this (does `E` accept this kind of argument?) but it doesn't seem possible without SFINAE.

Comment: The reason is because I have an f() that calls a g(). Inside g() I need to make a copy of the string. If it's a rvalue ref, I can just move it, so I want to preserve that. I can do it using std::forward if it's a T &&. But that will match any T.

Comment: Many things are possible, some are just really ugly: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aabb83e5138c6af7 (the `{}` are required here since I didn't want to implement copy/move ctors). Less ugly? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/169603c90b03f83c

Answer (score 1):

No, such thing is not possible.

If your function takes just one specified type, the best is to just create two functions, and not try to out-smart the language with tricks.

If you use template, then `f(1);` will set int as a template parameter. That is not what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something, this should work for what you are looking for.

```
void f(std::string&& arg)   // Take care of rvalues
{
  E(std::forward<std::string&&>(arg));
}

void f(std::string const& arg)   // Take care of lvalues
{
  E(std::forward<std::string const&>(arg));
}
```

I was able to test that using the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

void E(std::string const& s)
{
   std::cout << "Came to E(std::string const& )\n";
}

void E(std::string&& s)
{
   std::cout << "Came to E(std::string&& )\n";
}

void f(std::string&& arg)   // Take care of rvalues
{
   E(std::forward<std::string&&>(arg));
}

void f(std::string const& arg)   // Take care of lvalues
{
   E(std::forward<std::string const&>(arg));
}

int main()
{
   std::string s1("abcd");
   f(s1);
   f("xyx");
}
```

Output I got from running the program:

```
Came to E(std::string const& )
Came to E(std::string&& )
```

**Update**

Replacing the two overloaded implementations of `f` with a function template works just as well.

```
template <typename T>
void f(T&& arg)
{
   E(std::forward<T>(arg));
}

int main()
{
   std::string s1("abcd");
   f(s1);
   f("xyx");
}
```

If I add `f(1)` to `main`, there is a compiler error since there no overload of `E` that can work with that. If `E` itself is a function template, that strategy won't work.

The bottom line, I think, is that you have to prevent the ability to use anything but `std::string` only by not providing the ability to deal with such types at the level of `f` or at the level of `E`.

Comment: Yeah, that's the multiple versions that I know will work. It's fine, just wondering if there was a way to do it without that.

Comment: `std::forward` should only be used with a template parameter, or it will behave the same as `std::move`. And you should use `std::move` instead of `std::forward`.

Comment: @XinHuang: He should _not_ use `std::move` for the lvalue version, though. The argument should simply be passed along without anything else.

Comment: @Xeo Yes, you are right. The `std::forward` should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template <
    class T
  , class = typename std::enable_if<
         std::is_convertible<std::decay_t<T>, std::string const&>::value
      || std::is_convertible<std::decay_t<T>, std::string     &&>::value
    >::type
>
void f (T&& t) { E (std::forward<T> (t)); }
```